# Name of an algorithm that does dynamic value mapping on a scaling min/max basis?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, math, mapping

First off, I'm wondering if there's already an algorithm or a JS library that already solves the logic/problem I'm currently working on.

I'm working on an interactive project that uses generated data points from I/O sensors. The data points fluctuate between 0 and 100 (as an example). I need a function that will return a value that re-maps the value of the average of all the data points from one range to another while having dynamic floor and ceiling mapping values... Typically mapping functions would re-map a value between 0 to 100 into a value between 0 to 1 respectively. I'm looking for the best way so while the input values could range between 0 and 100, if the data points only range from 35-75, I would want the mapped value to be weighed as if those values were between 0 - 100. Is it like dynamic proportionate scaling or mapping?

It seems like this might be a problem that could already have been solved or have a standard algorithm to solve this logic... but I just don't know what it's called.

The parameters needed would be along the following lines:

- accepts a value that ranges between 0 and 100
- these values are stored in a dynamic array
- the values stored in the dynamic array are mapped to return a value between 0 and 1
- The mapped value needs to consider the fluctuating values max/min values stored in the array.
- the returned mapped value should adjust and account for the changing floor and ceil values used in the map function as these floor / ceil values are sourced from the min and max data points stored in the array.

Is there an algo or mathematic equation that exists to calculate simular logic? If not, I'd be interested in hearing some potential best solutions or logic for solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a *linear translation* of one coordinate system to another, in this case a 1-dimensional coordinate system. A real world example is where temperatures in degrees Celsius are converted to degrees Fahrenheit, or vice versa, but with a limit in range.

This can be implemented with a simple function that needs as input:

- One input value
- The min/max range of the input values
- The min/max range of the output values

It returns:

- The output value

The formula to perform the translation is:

```
(value - sourceLow) * (targetHigh - targetLow) / (sourceHigh - sourceLow)
```

This function then needs to be applied to all input values. It is clear that the input must have more than one distinct value, as otherwise the denominator of this expression is 0. If that happens you could default to outputting `targetLow` for this lonely input value.

Optionally, you could first have a preprocessing phase on all input values to dynamically determine the input range.

Here is an example in a runnable JavaScript snippet. The user can input a sequence of (space separated) input values, and then the algorithm kicks in:

- The min/max range is dynamically determined
- The mapping function is called on each input value, targeting a range of 0 to 1.

```js
function getRange(values) {
    return [Math.min(...values), Math.max(...values)];
}

function translate(value, sourceLow, sourceHigh, targetLow, targetHigh) {
    return (value - sourceLow) * (targetHigh - targetLow) / (sourceHigh - sourceLow);
}

function translateAll(values, sourceLow, sourceHigh, targetLow, targetHigh) {
     return values.map(value => translate(value, sourceLow, sourceHigh, targetLow, targetHigh));
}

// I/O management:

const [input, low, high, mapped] = document.querySelectorAll("input, span");

input.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    const values = input.value.match(/[+-]?[\d.]+/g).map(Number);
    const range = getRange(values);
    [low.textContent, high.textContent] = range;
    if (values.length < 2) {
        mapped.textContent = "0"; // Need more values
    } else {
        const result = translateAll(values, range[0], range[1], 0, 1);
        mapped.textContent = result.join(", ");
    }
}
```

```html
Input values: <input><br>
Input range: [<span></span> - <span></span>]<br>
Translated to [0 - 1]: <span></span>
```